# Delphi: Access Violation at the end of Create() constructor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a very basic and simple class like this:

unit Loader;

```
interface

uses
  Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TLoader = Class(TObject)
  published
      constructor Create();
  end;

implementation

{ TLoader }    
constructor TLoader.Create;
begin
   ShowMessage('ok');

end;

end.
```

And from Form1 i call it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 the : TLoader;
begin
  the := the.Create;
end;
```

Now, just after the `the := the.Create` part, delphi shows the message with `'ok'` and then gives me an error and says `Project Project1.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0040559d: read of address 0xffffffe4'.`

Also it shows this line:

```
constructor TLoader.Create;
begin
   ShowMessage('ok');

end; // <-------- THIS LINE IS MARKED AFTER THE ERROR.
```

I am new at delphi. I am using Delphi XE2 and i couldnt manage to fix this error. Does anyone show me a path or have solution for this?

Comment: I don't know what `var instance: TLoader` is supposed to do. Are you sure you need that global variable? It seems like you intend to declare local `TLoader` variables instead.

Comment: The question is **not** "How can i declare a class". Its an exception that throwed by Delphi and i couldn't realized that it was from wrong declaration. :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand i tried that part for solution and then of course realized that it was unnecessary.

Comment: @xangr My comment was not really aimed at you. This is an obvious duplicate. I'm sure I've answered it more than once. I'm sure both Andreas and Mason have too. But I couldn't quickly find a question to illustrate that. Stack Overflow search doesn't really work very well, but I suspect that it is a really **hard** problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i understand and i really dont know why i didn't see the mistake that i `made` in the `code`. I should know that `instance of object` issue. But i stuck at that point i was thinking it was from somewhere else :) I searched my stack error but couldn't find anything related to it :( Delphi must give us more detailed error instead of one line `Access Violation` error i guess.

Comment: It's hard to find duplicates of this question, @David, because it's hard to ask this question generically. We've seen many instances of the underlying problem, but each time, it's presented as a "debug my code" question because that's the only way to phrase the question from the point of view of someone who doesn't already know what's wrong.

Comment: Xangr, didn't the compiler warn you that you were using an uninitialized variable?

Comment: @RobKennedy nope :( Only access violation error when it comes to that part. Or i missed it but im sure there was no error like that you mentioned.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var
  the : TLoader;
begin
  the := the.Create;
```

is incorrect. It should be

```
var
  the : TLoader;
begin
  the := TLoader.Create;
```

Comment: I should sleep for few hours :( How can i miss that point! Thank you issue resolved! Thanks :)

Comment: @xangr - don't worry about it.  It's Delphi classic.  I've lost count of the number of times I've done this.

Comment: You should *the.ClassType().Create();* :-))))
PS. @Martin i believe you should call *inherited;* as well. Annoying, but that would make you more self for future refactors in bot h Delphi RTL core and your own code.

Comment: No, you can't do that, @Arioch. The `ClassType` function works by reading the class reference from the given object. In your suggestion, `ClassType` will be reading from an uninitialized variable because there is no valid object reference yet, which is the same problem the original question faced. `ClassType` is an instance method, so you need to have an instance.

Comment: @RobKennedy Well, yes. I should have thought about virtual constructors :-) Such shortcut could work in C++, but Delphi is too flexible to allow that :-)

Comment: What are you talking about, @Arioch? Virtual constructors have nothing to do with this. The `ClassType` function works the same in C++ Builder as it does in Delphi; the expression `the->ClassType()` on an uninitialized `the` variable is just as wrong in C++ as it is in Delphi. And in C++, how do you think it's a shortcut? C++ won't let you directly call the constructor of whatever `ClasssType` returns; code that doesn't work is not a shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

You've got the syntax wrong.  If you're constructing a new object, you should use the class name, not the variable name, in the constructor call:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 the : TLoader;
begin
  the := TLoader.Create;
end;
```