# raised exception class segmentation fault (11). delphi android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe6

Good morning, I'm having this problem when I rewrite the Create the form, and acessviolation when depurei the application before I realized the error raised exception class segmentation fault (11).

```
Tfrm_cart.Create constructor (AOwnerr: TComponent; ptipo1: String; PID1: Integer); 
begin 
   try 
     inherited Create (AOwnerr); 
     type: = ptipo1; 
     id: = PID1; 
  except 
     on e: Exception of 
       begin 
         ShowMessage (e.Message); 
       end; 

   end; 

end;
```

and to call it

```
 With frm_cart.Create (self, 'INC', 0) of 

      begin 
             frm_cart.Show; 
             Free; 
      End;
```

and took the automatic creation of forms in Delphi.

Anyone have any idea ??

Comment: See e.g. [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12203457/960757). You should write `frm_cart := Tfrm_cart.Create(Self, 'INC', 0);`, or `with Tfrm_cart.Create(Self, 'INC', 0) do`. P.S. don't swallow exceptions in your constructor.

Comment: I would also add the frm_cart.Show is going to be non-blocking so the form will also be destroyed before it gets painted on screen.  Most likely you simply need to drop the free as you have given it an owner which will destroy it later.

Comment: The code that you posted is not the real code because the constructor does not compile. Please always post real code.

Answer (score 1):

From what we can see in the question, it seems that you are attempting to create an instance of your form, but then calling the `Show` method on a different instance, `frm_cart`.

That in itself is surely wrong. Quite likely `frm_cart` is not initialised, hence the segmentation fault.

But the creation is also broken because you called the constructor on an instance rather than a class. The oldest mistake in the book.

You then call `Free` immediately after `Show` which also rather negates the utility of your code.

I expect that you should remove the `frm_cart` variable and write:

```
Tfrm_cart.Create(...).Show;
```

Also, swallowing exceptions is bad at the best of times, but is an gross error in a constructor. When a constructor raises an exception that means that the object has not been properly created. Attempting to continue as if the problem never happened is just postponing the pain.