# Calling Delphi constructor as an ordinary method - any hidden side effects?

Tags: delphi, constructor

I'm puzzled: why calling a Delphi constructor explicitly / as an ordinary method would not create a new instance / why no memory leaks?

Here's some sample code:

```
TMyHelperClass = class(TObject)
private
  fSomeHelperInt: integer;
public
  property SomeHelperInt : integer read fSomeHelperInt write fSomeHelperInt;
  constructor Create (const initSomeHelperInt : integer);
end;

TMyClass = class(TObject)
private
  fHelper : TMyHelperClass;
public
  constructor Create(const initSomeInt: integer);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  property Helper : TMyHelperClass read fHelper;
end;
```

Implementation:

```
constructor TMyHelperClass.Create(const initSomeHelperInt: integer);
begin
  fSomeHelperInt := initSomeHelperInt;
end;

constructor TMyClass.Create(const initSomeInt: integer);
begin
  fHelper := TMyHelperClass.Create(initSomeInt);
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  fHelper.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

And usage:

```
var
  my : TMyClass;
begin
  my := TMyClass.Create(2016);
  try
    //WHY is this ok to be used ?
    my.Helper.Create(2017);
  finally
    my.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How come I could call the TMyHelperClass+s Create constructor as an ordinary method? I mean - this IS exactly as I want it - but how come no issues (with memory)?

I guess the answer will be because the Create method was not called like TMyHelperClass.Create (to create an instance of TMyHelperClass)?

Is this way of calling the constructor as an ordinary method acceptable / ok to be used?

Comment: Read the documentation. It is explained there. And you do not want to do this. It is really bad practice. It breaks down as soon as your class owns any resource other than its own memory.  Create a separate public method that is called by the constructor.

Comment: Ah :( Was reading but obviously not very patient. Here it is:

Comment: When a constructor is called using an object reference (rather than a class reference), it does not create an object. Instead, the constructor operates on the specified object, executing only the statements in the constructor's implementation, and then returns a reference to the object

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: generally, you don't want to do this, but it makes sense when you do this inside another constructor. This probably the reason it is possible at all.

Comment: Consider that in this way your classes are coupled (TMyClass depends from TMyHelperClass) and you should find another way to do that in my opinion, maybe decoupling with an Interface

Comment: @Rudy Yes it is essential to call constructors this way inside other constructors but that's the only time it should ever be done.

Comment: @David: agreed. It should never be done outside another constructor.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can call the constructor as an ordinary method.
But it is bad practice to do so.

> why no memory leaks?

From: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Methods#Constructors

> When a constructor is called using an object reference (rather than a
>   class reference), it does not create an object. Instead, the
>   constructor operates on the specified object, executing only the
>   statements in the constructor's implementation, and then returns a
>   reference to the object. A constructor is typically invoked on an
>   object reference in conjunction with the reserved word inherited to
>   execute an inherited constructor.

The compiler will generate different code when calling `TObject.Create` *(class reference)* vs `AObject.Create` *(instance reference)*.

**Anti-pattern warning**
Abusing the constructor as a normal method will lead to problems when allocating resources.
Normally constructors and destructors are matched, but if you call the constructor twice (as you must when calling the constructor of an instance) you'll allocate the resource twice, but free it only once.

If you want to call the body of the constructor as a normal method, create a new method and call that method in the constructor.

E.g.:

```
constructor TTest.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  //Allocate needed resources here.
  Init;
end;

procedure TTest.Init;
begin
  //Do initialization stuff
  //But don't allocate any resources
```

Now you can safely call the `init` method whenever needed without any chance of mishaps.

The reason that it's possible to call a constructor without "constructing" anything is that the following code must work:

```
constructor TTest.Create(const AObject: TObject);
begin                //constructor of TTest happens here
  inherited Create;  //instance call to TParent.Create;
  //Other code
end;
```

In very rare cases you can skip the class call to the constructor entirely.
The following code will work:

```
MyTest:= TTest.NewInstance;
//Voodoo code here.
MyTest.Create;
```

This can be used to prevent the compiler from inserting the automatic code that gets generated in a call to `TTest.Create`.
This is very rarely needed and in 20 years of coding I've only ever used it once.
The use case for this was speed sensitive code where I wanted to avoid the overhead of exception checking and zeroing out of allocated space, this was before Delphi supported records with methods.

If I had to do that code again I'd use a record and just allocate a pool of 1000 records on the heap and hand them out as needed.

Comment: "You can also do more advanced stuff, like skip `TParent.Create` and call `TGrandParent.Create`" -- Which may cause `TParent`'s fields to not get initialised properly. Don't do this unless you know what you're doing. I think a better explanation is the few rare times you need to call `NewInstance` explicitly, followed by other code, followed by `Create` on that instance.

Comment: @hvd, thanks much better. That exact use case is of course why regular calls to a constructor are possible in the first place.

Comment: FWIW, my use case was a constructor of another class triggering events it shouldn't (in other classes). I created the class with `NewInstance`, saved a reference to it, and ignored the events if they came from the class under construction. Avoiding zeroing out allocated space makes sense too, but I wasn't aware that there was a difference in exception handling (it's been a long while for me as well), I probably misremembered, but I thought `MyTest.Create` would still free the instance if an exception happened during construction. If not, thanks for that.

Comment: not only inherited constructors, but you might have several overloaded constructors with different parameters

Comment: Agree with Arioch. Calling overloaded constructor is probably the more common use case. It's perhaps also worth noting that the fact that Delphi allows this leads to a fairly common beginner mistake: `ObjRef := ObjRef.Create();` (instead of `ObjRej := ClassRef.Create();`) Here's an [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12203457/224704) about this kind of mistake.

Comment: @Shaun - when you want to revise a documentation link, leave out the version and the wiki will redirect to the latest. Like this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods#Constructors . Then you won't need to revise it the next year.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Oh that's great. Thanks. I didn't know.