# Why I cannot create a simple dictionary here

Tags: dictionary, hashmap, freepascal

I am trying to create and use a simple dictionary using TFPGmap:

```
program rnTFPGmap; 
{$mode objfpc}
uses fgl; 

var 
    mydict: specialize TFPGmap<string, string>; 
    key: string; 
    i: longint; 

begin
    mydict.create; 
    mydict.add('k1','v1'); 
    mydict.add('k2','v2');
    mydict.add('k3','v3');
    //for key in mydict.keys do   {does not work either;}
    for i := 1 to length(mydict) do  {line 17: first error from here. }
        writeln(mydict[i]); 
end.
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
$ fpc soq_rntfpgmap
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0+dfsg-11+deb9u1 [2017/06/10] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2015 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling soq_rntfpgmap.pas
soq_rntfpgmap.pas(17,16) Error: Type mismatch
soq_rntfpgmap.pas(18,19) Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "LongInt", expected "ShortString"
soq_rntfpgmap.pas(22) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

Edit: I tried to modify the code according to documentation and came up with following version:

```
program rnTFPGmap; 
{$mode objfpc}
uses fgl; 
type 
    tuple = specialize TFPGmap<string, string>; 
    mydict = Array of tuple;
var 
    dict: mydict; 
    i: tuple; 
    item: string; 
begin
    setlength(dict, length(dict)+3); 
    dict.add('k1','v1');   {error on this line: "CREATE" expected but "ADD" found}
    dict.add('k2','v2');
    dict.add('k3','v3');
    writeln('dict.count: ', dict.count); 
    for i in dict do    
            writeln(i); 
end.
```

But I am now getting following error:

```
$ fpc soq_rntfpgmap
Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0+dfsg-11+deb9u1 [2017/06/10] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2015 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling soq_rntfpgmap.pas
soq_rntfpgmap.pas(13,25) Warning: Variable "dict" of a managed type does not seem to be initialized
soq_rntfpgmap.pas(14,7) Fatal: Syntax error, "CREATE" expected but "ADD" found
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

Not able to sort this out.

Comment: Why do you think Length can be used here? What are you using as a reference? It looks like you are guessing. I could tell you the answer but the questions will keep coming until you start using a proper reference. Also, that's not how you instantiate an object. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12203457/505088 Also, we count zero based in this language.

Comment: I tried: `for i := 0 to mydict.count do writeln(mydict[i]);` but got error: `Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "LongInt", expected "ShortString"
`

Comment: Some docs that I am using: http://newpascal.org/assets/modern_pascal_introduction.html , https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Main_Page , https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/ and https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/ref.html

Comment: The key one that you are missing is the documentation for the class that you are using. I could give you the link, but it might be nice to find it for yourself with websearch. It has all the answers.

Comment: https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/fgl/tfpgmap.html  does not have any examples. And it does not mention count or length, though I find `dict.count` works.

Comment: No. But it documents the class and from that you can see what is wrong with your code. And if you read that page carefully you can see precisely which methods you need to call. Don't be scared to spend time reading. And `Count` is documented, that's in the properties. I can assure you that all that you need is there, you need to apply yourself with more belief and patience. I'm sorry if this sounds patronising but I firmly believe that if you learn how to solve problems for yourself better that is an infinitely preferable outcome for you.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: This isn't a delphi question.

Comment: Just start at the very beginning. See if you can successfully create an instance of the class and add a single key/value pair to it. At the moment you haven't managed to create an instance. That is so basic you aren't going to get anywhere until you understand how to do that. It's a waste of your time trying to do anything else until you learn how to create instances. I even gave you a link pointing out the error in your original code. If we answer then you'll just copy the code and learn nothing.

Comment: I am able to make a dictionary using `record` but not using `TFPGmap`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Pl see my solution as an answer here.

Comment: Well done, I applaud your persistence and attitude!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code works. See comments for some explanations:

```
program rnTFPGmap; 
{$mode objfpc}
uses fgl; 
type 
    Rndict = specialize TFPGmap<string, string>;{define type under type}
var 
    dict: Rndict;               {define object under var}
    i: integer; 
{main: }
begin
    dict := Rndict.Create;      {create object in main}
    dict.add('k1','v1'); 
    dict.add('k2','v2'); 
    dict.add('k3','v3'); 
    for i := 0 to (dict.count-1) do begin 
        writeln('i: ',i, '; key: ', dict.getkey(i), '; value: ', dict.getdata(i)); 
        end; 
end.
```

Output:

```
i: 0; key: k1; value: v1
i: 1; key: k2; value: v2
i: 2; key: k3; value: v3
```

I thank @DavidHeffernan for his guidance.