# Delphi Access violation creating TFileStream

Tags: delphi

I receive an access violation creating a TFileStream object, on fs.create(...), but I really don't know whats wrong

```
var
  sr: TStreamReader;
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
   try
      fs.Create('aaa.ini',fmOpenRead);
      sr := tStreamReader.Create(fs,TEncoding.UTF8);
       with connAtomo do begin
        Close;
        with Params do begin
          Clear;
          while not sr.EndOfStream do begin
            add(sr.ReadLine);
          end;
        end;
      end;
      sr.Free;
      fs.free
   except
      on e: EFileStreamError do  begin
         showmessage('File error '+e.Message);
      end;
   end;
```

Comment: `fs.Create('aaa.ini',fmOpenRead);` must be `fs := TFileStream.Create('aaa.ini',fmOpenRead);`. Also, you must use two nested `try..finally` blocks to protect your resources. `Frog := TFrog.Create; try { use frog } finally Frog.Free end`.

Comment: How is it you know how to correctly create a `TStreamReader` but don't know how to create a `TFileStream`? The syntax is exactly the same - `sr := TStreamReader.Create` and `fs := TFileStream.Create`.

Comment: This question has an incorrect close reason. Should be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203457/delphi-access-violation-at-the-end-of-create-constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access violation is caused by the wrong way to create a TFileStream instance, resulting is `fs` variable having an invalid value. As with any other object, you have to call the class constructor and assign the result to the variable: `fs := TFileStreaM.create('aaa.ini', fmOpenRead);`.

I have revised your code:

```
var
  sr : TStreamReader;
  fs : TFileStream;
begin
   try
     fs := TFileStream.Create('aaa.ini', fmOpenRead);
     try
       sr := tStreamReader.Create(fs, TEncoding.UTF8);
       try
         connAtomo.Close;
         connAtomo.Params.Clear;
         while not sr.EndOfStream do
           connAtomo.Params.Add(sr.ReadLine);
       finally
         sr.Free;
       end;
     finally
       fs.Free
     end;
   except
      on E: EFileStreamError do
         ShowMessage('File error ' + E.Message);
   end;
end;
```

As you can see, I have used `try/finally` to protect the allocated objects and remove the `with` usage which is not recommended.

Comment: That relative path looks scary too.

Comment: Why have you written this answer? You don't explain what is wrong. And what is wrong is a classic issue which has already been answered. We should close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank Fpiette and Andreas i was in urgent i have forgotten some code but the answer was so useful for me and  fix my problem. Sorry